# Array of objects in Swagger

Tags: laravel, swagger

I am new to Swagger. I am using DarkaOnline Swagger UI (OAS3).
I have a JSON  request body like this

```
{
 "CurrentPuzzle": "1",
 "OpenedLevel": "10",
 "RewardPuzzlePiecess": 
     [
       1,
       2,
     ]
 }
```

I need to define this in swagger model. What I tried so far is I defined the following in swagger controller :

```
/**
 * @OA\Post(path="/gameData",
 *   tags={"user"},
 *   summary="Add Game Data of User",
 *   security={{"bearerAuth":{}}}, *  
 *   description="",
 *   operationId="gameData",
 *   @OA\RequestBody(
 *       required=true,
 *       description="Created user object",
 *       @OA\JsonContent(
 *          type="object",
 *           @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Game")
 *       )
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(response="default", description="successful operation")
 * )
 */
public function gameData()
{
}
```

In Game Model :

```
/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *      type="object",
 *      @OA\Items(
 *           @OA\Property(
 *               type="integer",
 *               description="The puzzle",
 *               @OA\Schema(type="array")
 *           ),
 *           @OA\Property(
 *               type="integer",
 *               description="The level",
 *               @OA\Schema(type="integer")
 *           ),
 *           @OA\Property(
 *               type="array",
 *               description="The survey ID",
 *               @OA\Items(
 *                 type="string",
 *               ),
 *               @OA\Schema(type="array")
 *           ),
 *      ),
 *      description="Store User Survey Results"
 * )
 * @var array
 */
 public $SurveyDataList;
```

After running, I am getting only an empty object in swagger ui like this {}.

Comment: /**
 * @OA\Schema(@OA\Xml(name="Game"))
 */
class Game
{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ,
in my controller I defined my gameData function like this,

```
/**
 * @OA\Post(path="/gameData",
 *   tags={"user"},
 *   summary="Add Game Data of User",
 *   security={{"bearerAuth":{}}}, *  
 *   description="",
 *   operationId="gameData",
 *   @OA\RequestBody(
 *       required=true,
 *       description="Created user object",
 *       @OA\JsonContent(
 *           ref="#/components/schemas/Game"
 *       )
 *   ),
 *   @OA\Response(response="default", description="successful operation")
 * )
 */
public function gameData()
{
}
```

And in model.. I defined 3 properties where two of them are of type numbers and thirs one as array with Items in it.

```
/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *      property="CurrentPuzzle",
 *      type="number",
 *      enum="1",
 *      description="Store current puzzle"
 * )
 */

 /**
 * @OA\Property(
 *      property="OpenedLevel",
 *      type="number",
 *      enum="1",
 *      description="Store current level"
 * )
 */


 /**
 * @OA\Property(
 *      property="RewardPuzzlePiecess",
 *      type="array",
 * *      @OA\Items(
 *               type="number",
 *               description="The survey ID",
 *               @OA\Schema(type="number")
 *         ),
 *      description="Store reward index"
 * )
 */
```